How to create connection to create - queue item - HTTP Trigger - local - Azurite - Azure Queue Storage
I installed Azurite and started  ( assuming the command is correct.)

azurite --queueHost 127.0.0.1

I created an outqueue using Azure Storage Explorer
I want to test/use this function
const { app, output } = require('@azure/functions');

const queueOutput = output.storageQueue({
    queueName: 'outqueue',
    connection: 'MyStorageConnectionAppSetting',
});

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    extraOutputs: [queueOutput],
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const body = await request.text();
        context.extraOutputs.set(queueOutput, body);
        return { body: 'Created queue item.' };
    },
});

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-javascript
What I dont know / understand is "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting" .
(The name of an app setting or setting collection that specifies how to connect to Azure Queues. See Connections.)
Error

[2024-04-22T11:04:11.464Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while
executing function: Functions.httpTrigger1.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues: Storage account
connection string 'AzureWebJobsMyStorageConnectionAppSetting' does not
exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.

what is the step I am missing to create that MyStorageConnectionAppSetting ? Any reference documentation that gives the steps is appreciated.
Thank you

To resolve the error, use the application setting "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" in the local.settings.json to enable storage connection locally.
local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}

Change the Connection name in the function code.
Code Snippet:
const { app, output } = require('@azure/functions');

const queueOutput = output.storageQueue({
    queueName: 'outqueue',
    connection: 'AzureWebJobsStorage ',
});

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    extraOutputs: [queueOutput],
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const body = await request.text();
        context.extraOutputs.set(queueOutput, body);
        return { body: 'Created queue item.' };
    },
});

Run the function locally:
C:\Users\uname\function>func start

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5611 Commit hash: N/A +591b8aec842e333a87ea9e23ba390bb5effe0655 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.31.1.22191

[2024-04-22T13:17:40.044Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        httpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/httpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-04-22T13:17:53.133Z] Executing 'Functions.httpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=00ec97ec-a464-43af-acff-854c28b43711)
[2024-04-22T13:17:56.667Z] Executed 'Functions.httpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=00ec97ec-a464-43af-acff-854c28b43711, Duration=3631ms)

Response:


Looks promising. sorry I am a starter, I have a question about this - "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting":"<Storage_Connection_String>". From where can I get that information. I am using local environment azurite.

You can copy the connection string from Portal=>Azure Storage account=>Security+Networking=>Access leys=>Connection String.

How can I make use of local ? I presume you understood the goal, developing this locally.

You can use AzureWebJobsStorage instead of MyStorageConnectionAppSetting as value to the connection in the code.

As I have created Queue in Azure, I have used Azure Storage Connection string in my case.

I can accept answer, if you make this shorter. Because the simple answer is connection: "AzureWebJobsStorage", and local settings is "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", for local emulator. Thanks
